# Export as PDF UI Scene(QML)

Tags: qt, qml

I want the images and texts appearing in the interface to be rendered as PDF. I have a button and when the button is triggered, it saves whatever is on the screen that appears in the interface as a PDF(like export as PDF) . For this, I looked at the resources and the topics opened in the forum, but I could not reach a clear result. I would be very happy if you could help with this.

Comment: I didn't understand, you want to write pdf reader app like adobe Acrobat? because you say   `images and texts appearing in the interface to be rendered as PDF.` this thing didn't relate to your title. Export pdf is different.

Comment: If you want to export your qml Item in pdf , you should create one class in c++ that its job is printing and exporting. To do this you need `QPrinter`. [This Example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-richtext-textedit-example.html) do this by using c++.  In qml, there isn't any option like `QPrinter` for doing this but you can create a class and call export function in qml.I hope I was able to get what I meant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should enable `PrintSupport` module in your `.pro` file like `QT+=PrintSupport`

First declare Drawer class like this :

```
#pragma once
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>

class PdfExporter : public QQmlApplicationEngine
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    PdfExporter(QQmlApplicationEngine * engine);
    Q_INVOKABLE void screenShot();
private:
    QQmlApplicationEngine * mEngine;
};
```

and define:

```
#include <Drawer.h>
#include <QQuickWindow>
#include <QPrinter>
#include <QPainter>

PdfExporter::PdfExporter(QQmlApplicationEngine *engine) : QQmlApplicationEngine(engine), mEngine(engine)
{

}

void PdfExporter::screenShot()
{
    foreach(QObject* obj, mEngine->rootObjects()) {
      QQuickWindow* window = qobject_cast<QQuickWindow*>(obj);
      if (window)
      {
        QImage windowImage = window->grabWindow();
        QPrinter pdfPrinter(QPrinter::HighResolution);
        pdfPrinter.setOutputFormat(QPrinter::PdfFormat);
        pdfPrinter.setOutputFileName("test.pdf");
        QPainter painter;
        painter.begin(&pdfPrinter);
        painter.drawImage(QRect(0,0,windowImage.width(),windowImage.height()),windowImage,{0,0,windowImage.width(),windowImage.height()});
        painter.end();
      }
    }
}
```

In the `main.cpp` I preferred to export C++ class as context property to engine.

```
 PdfExporter * dr = new PdfExporter(&engine);
 engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("drawer",dr);
```

In QML you can trigger function like :

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.12

Window {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    ColumnLayout
    {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        Rectangle
        {
            Layout.preferredWidth:  200
            Layout.preferredHeight:  100
            color: "red"
        }

        Button
        {
            Layout.preferredWidth:  100
            Layout.preferredHeight:  20
            Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignHCenter
            text: "test"
            onClicked: drawer.screenShot()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry for the late reply. I didn't get notification. Your method worked, but the resolution is too bad Do you have a suggestion for this?